# Keep jquery option value, save user's value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, date

I'm trying to achieve something quite small. I'll try my best to explain it.

I have an option form with multiple selects, year, month and date. Whenever the user selects something, the form is submitted so that I can fetch data from a database.

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
<select class="form-control" id="day" name="day" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option>- Dummy option -</option>
       <option>- Dummy option -</option>
       <option>- Dummy option -</option>
       <option>- Dummy option -</option>
</select>
</form>
```

One for day, month and year.

Element's IDs are `"day", "month", "year"`.

I'm trying to show today's date by default, which automatically fetches today's information.

As i'm relatively new to JS/JQ, I've tried this to set the options to today's date :

```
var fYear = CurrentDate.getFullYear();
var fMonth = CurrentDate.getMonth()+1;
var fDay = CurrentDate.getDate();

$("#year").val(fYear);
$("#month").val(fMonth);
$("#day").val(fDay);
```

Problem is that whenever the user selects an option, it keeps re-appending today's date, overriding the user's selection.

-- **Question** --

How would I go about only showing today's date when the user hasn't done anything to the select form? Only show the date if the form hasn't been changed by the user.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you submitting the form? can you post your form too?

Comment: onchange="this.form.submit(), whenever an option is selected, the form is submitted automatically.

Comment: This is what i want to see where you are submitting it, actually i just want to know the action of the form?

Comment: Yeap, this is a php page/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you probably want to use [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which will allow you to submit your form without refreshing your page.

Assuming your page is called `page.html` and your HTML looked something like -

```
<form id="myform" role="form" action="" method="post">
  <select class="form-control" id="day" name="day" onchange="this.form.submit()">
   <option>- Dummy option -</option>
   <option>- Dummy option -</option>
   <option>- Dummy option -</option>
   <option>- Dummy option -</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Your javascript should be something like

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "page.html",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
      ..... do something with the result
    },
    error: function() {
      ..... report the error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @john C, this sounds interesting and I will try it out right away! I'll let you know if this has worked. Also, are you missing a ( ,$this().serialize ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it should have been `$(this).serialize()`; I've corrected it now.

Comment: As for now, using Ajax is simply the best solution to this whole ordeal. I haven't used Ajax, since I've created some PHP checks to determine if the date is set or not, if not, append it.

If I had not used PHP, I would have used @John c's solution, which works too. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Before assigning default values in your jQuery code, you can check if the dropdown has a selected value or not. If not, then you can assign default value.

```
if($('#year').val() == ''){
    $('#year').val('fYear');
}
```

Comment: won't work at all, as the form is getting submitted so page refreshes and current date gets appended.

Comment: In your server code, you can check `POST` data for selected value and then add the attribute `selected="selected"` in the `<option>` tag with that value

Answer (score 1):

why dont you reset the all the date fields on page load by a class selector `.date` and then set today's date.

**HTML Code:**

```
<input class="dt" type="text" name="date"/>
<input class="dt" type="text" name="month"/>
<input class="dt" type="text" name="year"/>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(".dt").val(''); 
    $("#year").val(fYear);
    $("#month").val(fMonth);
    $("#day").val(fDay);
});
```

Comment: Might have been unclear myself, but this does not bring me the desired result.